# Copying content from one Portal for ArcGIS to another using Python?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-online, arcgis-portal

I am trying to copy content from one portal to another with python only, **without** using AGO assistant https://ago-assistant.esri.com/, as this doesn't work behind our firewall in our test network. I have explored these links for obtaining the correct python script to be able to perform the task: https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools/tree/master/samples but I don't know which script works for the copying of content from one to another? If anyone has used these, simply pass on the name of the script and that will suffice this request?

Comment: Not sure if ago-tools does what you want, have you looked into [ArcRest](https://github.com/Esri/ArcREST/tree/master/samples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is located here: [moveitemsReassignGroups](https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools/blob/master/samples/moveItemsReassignGroups.py) replace user name and/or  and  to reassign groups and content from one place to another. Option 2 includes migrating accounts with this link: [migrateAccounts](https://github.com/Esri/ago-tools/blob/master/samples/migrateAccount.py)

Answer (score 0):

To do this I suggest looking at Esri's [portalpy](https://github.com/Esri/portalpy) which is:

> A module that allows you to administer Portal for ArcGIS and ArcGIS
>   Online.